# How can I return the column value where the index is greater than an integer and smaller than previouse index is smaller?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a small df like this:

```
Interval  Factor Prev_Interval                              
0.0002     1.0      0.0000
0.0005     1.5      0.0002
0.0010     2.0      0.0005
0.0050     2.5      0.0010
0.0150     3.0      0.0050
0.0500     3.5      0.0150
0.2500     4.0      0.0500
0.5000     4.2      0.2500
2.0000     4.3      0.5000
```

I need to find the 'Factor' where a float I calculated is < prev_interval and > Interval. So, if the float I calculates = 0.010, the output is 3.0 - i.e. between 0.0050 and 0.015.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intervals are sorted and successive, the most efficient is to use [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html):

```
x = 0.010

out = df['Factor'].iloc[np.searchsorted(df['Interval'], x)]
```

A generic solution using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df.loc[df['Interval'].gt(x) & df['Prev_Interval'].lt(x), 'Factor'].squeeze()
```

Output: `3.0`

Comment: Life-saver, thx a lot!